# Showing correlated errors in a scatterplot

Tags: data-visualization, covariance, scatterplot

I have 10 measurements $(x, y)_i \in \mathbb{R}^2, \, i \in 1..10$. Each is measured with uncertainty in both x and y. Furthermore, each measurement and its uncertainty is correlated with each other measurement, and I know the full covariance matrix.

What is the best way to show this graphically?

Comment: To help us understand your situation, can you post a small example dataset?